# Dynamic javascript that is echoed by php doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm echoing a javascript snippet with php. the problem is that when I load that snippet dynamically, it doesn't work. but when I put generated javascript right in the place and comment the php, it works.

CODE :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   2,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   600,        // Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                // Size & Position
                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                // Components
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                thumb_links             :   0,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                    <?php
                        $loop = new WP_Query('post_type=slide');
                        if($loop->have_posts()):while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();
                    ?>
                    {
                        image : '<?php the_field('slide_pic'); ?>',
                        title : '<h2><?php the_content(); ?></h2>',
                        thumb : '',
                        url : ''
                    },

                    <?php endwhile;endif;wp_reset_query(); ?>
                ],

                // Theme Options
                progress_bar            :   0,          // Timer for each slide
                mouse_scrub             :   0

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Generated javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).load(function(){
            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   2,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   600,        // Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                // Size & Position
                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                // Components
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                thumb_links             :   0,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                        {
                        image : 'http://mahpari.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/image4.jpg',
                        title : '<h2><p>شعار مورد نظر 2</p>
</h2>',
                        thumb : '',
                        url : ''
                    },

                                        {
                        image : 'http://mahpari.dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/image1.jpg',
                        title : '<h2><p>شعار مورد نظر 1</p>
</h2>',
                        thumb : '',
                        url : ''
                    },

                                    ],

                // Theme Options
                progress_bar            :   0,          // Timer for each slide
                mouse_scrub             :   0

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're directly dumping text from PHP into a Javascript context, which means you **HAVE** to make sure you're generating syntactically correct JS code. You should ALWAYS be using `json_encode()` to do that, so you don't introduce any JS syntax errors and kill the entire code block.

Comment: Also, those special characters need to be encoded or Javascript isn't going to like it. Nor does it like multi-line strings.

Comment: @MarcB, why should I use json encode? can you put your snippet of code?

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode(get_the_whatever()) ?>`, basically

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the line breaks. This will produce an error. (`SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF`)

```
title : '<h2><p>شعار مورد نظر 2</p>
</h2>',
```

It should be better like that:

```
title : '<h2><p>شعار مورد نظر 2</p>\n</h2>',
```

Comment: if I delete title data, it again doesn't show the image I want to show in slider

Comment: Open your console. Are there any errors? (BTW You shouldn't delete the title but escape the line break.)

Answer (score 0):

Here, at the end of your "while" loop:

```
       url : ''
    },   // <--dangling comma
        ],
```

Internet Explorer is particular harsh on those and will puke with a syntax error.

Comment: I've tried this solution but it doesn't work. would you place your json_encode version?

Comment: you were right. change your answer to get a tick. :) json version